# C# Update Connection String Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql

I am having some connectivity issues with `Visual Studio` and `SQL Server`.

This is the connections string in my `web.config` file;

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WintipToysConnectionString" connectionString="Data 
Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=WINGTIPTOYS;Integrated 
Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

According to my `DB connection string` found in `Visual Studio`, my `connection string` is;

```
    Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=WINGTIPTOYS;Integrated Security=True
```

Which seems to add up - but, I get this **error** when my program hits a certain line;

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50
>   - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

I am actually following the *WingTipToys* tutorial on the *Microsoft* website and I am struggling to get it to use the Database I attached to **SSMS**.

I can write queries inside `VS` which works fine. So I don't really understand why my program is having this **error** when running?

Thanks.

Comment: "See the Windows Application event log for error details." Have you looked in the event logs as suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly haven't used SQLExpress in a looong time. It looks like the syntax you're using is for an "instance" - which is pointed out in the error message:

> *...Cannot create an automatic instance...*

What you have does *look* like  `server\instance` conn string syntax...

Connect to the "default" instance of SQL Express like so: `Data Source=.\\SQLExpress`

Refer to this:

- [SSE Connection string sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sse)

Hth...

Comment: Thank you - this along with another minor edit I needed to do has fixed my issue. Thanks!